# Is there a SQL keyword meaning "Don't Change"?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, keyword, default-value

Currently, SQL lets you use the keyword **DEFAULT** when inserting or updating a record, to tell the database to just use the column's default data type value:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET COL_A = DEFAULT, COL_B = 'hello' WHERE ID = 123
```

For example, if COL_A's data type is VARCHAR2, the statement will insert NULL in COL_A.

However, what if I wanted to perform the update, but leave COL_A unchanged? I know you'll probably say, just remove COL_A from the update statement. But, let's say hypothetically that COL_A has to be in the statement. Is there a keyword to let SQL know to leave COL_A's value unchanged?

For example, I was thinking it might be something like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET COL_A = NOCHANGE, COL_B = 'hello' WHERE ID = 123
```

But that doesn't work obviously.

Comment: `Col_A = Col_A`  Don't overthink this one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use the column name itself:

```
UPDATE TABLE
    SET COL_A = COL_A, COL_B = 'hello'
    WHERE ID = 123;
```

This will work in any database.  This is commonly used for "partial" updates:

```
UPDATE TABLE
    SET COL_A = (CASE WHEN foo = 'bar' THEN 'baz' ELSE COL_A END),
        COL_B = 'hello'
    WHERE ID = 123;
```

`COL_B` is always updated.  `COL_A` is only updated sometimes.

Comment: Fantastic solution (the CASE WHEN piece is just what I needed)